# How do I download contents of a folder from oracle cloud storage classic container using the requests package for python?

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x, python-requests, cloud

I have a folder named 'test1' inside the container 'test' (/test/test1/).
How do I download the objects using this prefix in `requests` package for python?

For downloading a file under container, I've the following code:

```
def download_file_oraclecloud(self,
                              ora_url,
                              username,
                              password,
                              container_name,
                              file_name,
                              local_file_name,
                              url) :

    # url='https://storage.us2.oraclecloud.com/v1/Storage-a428615/'
    token = self.create_session_oraclecloud(ora_url,username,password)
    headers= {
        'X-Auth-Token':token,
    }
    response=requests.get(url+container_name+'/'+file_name,open(local_file_name, 'wb'),headers=headers)
```

How can I download the contents of a folder?

Answer (score 0):

The object store does have a REST API [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/storage-cloud/ssapi/toc.htm)

1. get your username, password, and your auth url (it should end in `auth/v1.0`)
2. send a get request to the auth url with your username and password as headers
3. save the `X-Auth-Token` from the response
4. make a get request for the objects you'd like to download [see this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/storage-cloud/cssto/downloading-object.html)

This blog post provides a pretty good walk-through too
https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/playing-around-with-the-oracle-storage-cloud-service-v2